# IIS 6.0 Virtual Directory setup

Tags: iis, iis-6, directory, virtual

I set up a website and I created a folder names (docs) in the website as Virtual Directory with some documents.

Therefore the URL is xxxxxxyyyyzzzz.com/docs

The problem is that when i try to access xxxxxxyyyyzzzz.com/docs/1.doc, Authentication is required. Can you tell me how to remove this and leave any user access this folder with any restrictions?

David

Comment: Which authentication system is causing you problems? IIS build in or have you got .NET on the machien which is restricting access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two support documents that assist 1.) with the [setup of Virtual Directories][1], and 2.) [how to manage folder permissions in IIS][2].

I hope that this gives some guidance for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a programming question, but if you lauch IIS manager, right click on your virtual directory, click Edit under Anonymous access and authentication control, choose "directory security" and select "anonymous".

You will also need to make sure the anonymous IIS account has read access to the directory in question (the account is shown on the screen where you enable/disable anonymous access).

Answer (score 0):

Check you have anonymous access allowed with a valid account under `Properties| Directory Security | Authentication and access control | Edit...`